# scipy.optimize with non linear constraints

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have non-linear function with non-linear constraints and I'd like to optimize it. I don't know how to define non-linear constraints using scipy.optimize. My code so far looks like:

```
from math import cos, atan
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import sympy as sy

def f(x):
    return 0.1*x*y

def ineq_constraint(x):
    x**2 + y**2 - (5+2.2*sy.cos(10*sy.atan(x/y)))**2
    return x,y

con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': ineq_constraint}
minimize(f,x0,method='SLSQP',constraints=con)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The were a few minor issues with the code; here is the modified version (explanation below):

```
from math import cos, atan
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(x):
    return 0.1 * x[0] * x[1]

def ineq_constraint(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 - (5. + 2.2 * cos(10 * atan(x[0] / x[1])))**2


con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': ineq_constraint}
x0 = [1, 1]
res = minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=con)
```

The `res` looks as follows:

```
     fun: 0.37229877398896682
     jac: array([ 0.16372866,  0.22738743,  0.        ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 96
     nit: 22
    njev: 22
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 2.27385837,  1.63729975])
```

One problem was that `x` and `y` were not defined in your functions, I replaced them by `x[0]` and `x[1]`, respectively; also there was no need to use `sympy` to define your constraints and you want to return the actual constraint and not `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Shouldn't 'ineq' instead be 'eq', since this is an equality constraint?

Comment: @BernardoCosta: Don't know; I just copied it from the question :)

Comment: can use it within [NonlinearConstraint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html) for more accurate calculations