# Optimize a non linear function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have a function in python which looks like this:

```
import numpy as np    

def fun(Gp,Ra,Mr,Pot,Sp,Mc,Keep):
   if(Keep==True):
     return(Pot*np.tanh((Gp+Ra+Mr+ Mc)*Sp ))
```

Assuming the following data:

```
   import pandas as pd
dt_org = pd.DataFrame({"RA": [0.5, 0.8, 0.9],
                   "MR": [0.97, 0.95, 0.99],
                   "POT": [0.25, 0.12, 0.05],
                   "SP": [0.25, 0.12, 0.15],
                   "MC": [50, 75, 100],
                   "COUNTRY": ["GB", "IR", "GR"]
                   })
```

I have in total **100** `GP` and i want to **allocate all of them** properly
in order to maximize the `objective_function`:

under the restriction that **all** the 3 elements are **positive**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309877/scipy-optimize-with-non-linear-constraints) post the `scipy.optimize` would be the way to go, but i am confused in order how to write the problem down

**Update: my try**

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

y = {'A': {'RA': 0.5, 'MR': 0.97, 'POT': 0.25, 'SP': 0.25, 'MC': MC_1, 'keep': True},
     'B': {'RA': 0.8, 'MR': 0.95, 'POT': 0.12, 'SP': 0.12, 'MC': MC_2, 'keep': True},
         'C': {'RA': 0.9, 'MR': 0.99, 'POT': 0.05, 'SP': 0.15, 'MC': MC_3, 'keep': True}}

def objective_function(x):
                return(
                     -(fun(x[0], Ra=y['A']['RA'], Mr=y['A']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['A']['POT'], Sp=y['A']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['A']['MC'], Keep=y['A']['keep']) +
                       fun(x[1], Ra=y['B']['RA'], Mr=y['B']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['B']['POT'], Sp=y['B']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['B']['MC'], Keep=y['B']['keep']) +
                       fun(x[2], Ra=y['C']['RA'], Mr=y['C']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['C']['POT'], Sp=y['C']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['C']['MC'], Keep=y['C']['keep']))
                )

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 100})

bnds = ((0, None), (0, None), (0, None))

minimize(objective_function, x0=[1,1,1],   args=y, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,
             constraints=cons)
```

The problem now is that i get the error `ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar`, whereas the output of the `fun` function is a scalar

**UPDATE 2 (after @Cleb comment)**
So now i changed the function in:

```
def objective_function(x,y):

                temp =   -(fun(x[0], Ra=y['A']['RA'], Mr=y['A']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['A']['POT'], Sp=y['A']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['A']['MC'], Keep=y['A']['keep']) +
                       fun(x[1], Ra=y['B']['RA'], Mr=y['B']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['B']['POT'], Sp=y['B']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['B']['MC'], Keep=y['B']['keep']) +
                       fun(x[2], Ra=y['C']['RA'], Mr=y['C']['MR'],
                                             Pot=y['C']['POT'], Sp=y['C']['SP'],
                                             Mc=y['C']['MC'], Keep=y['C']['keep']))


                print("GP for the 1st: " + str(x[0]))
                print("GP for the 2nd: " + str(x[1]))
                print("GP for the 3rd: " + str(x[2]))
        return(temp)

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 100})

bnds = ((0, None), (0, None), (0, None))
```

Now there are 2 problems: 
 1. the values of `x[0],x[1],x[2]` are really close to each other

2. the sum of `x[0],x[1],x[2]` is over 100

Comment: Read their tutorial (scipy.optimize; tutorial != API docs; it's quite good) and try something. You may be confused, but not trying and showing anything always looks like: write that code for me.

Comment: please see update

Comment: That's code but there is no description about potential problems it has.

Comment: I might miss something but in your `objective_function`, you only pass `x` but not `y`; in `fun` you only pass parameters but no `x` (this function seems to be independent of x, that seems funky). And I also agree with sascha: an actual question would help to help you :)

Comment: @Cleb i pass y in the `args` argument in the `minimize` function. The problem now is that i get the error `ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar`, whereas the output of the `fun` function is a scalar

Comment: You need to feed `x` to `fun` in the function definition; you try to optimize something in dependency of `x` but you don't pass it to `fun`. And you still need to feed`y` to your `objective_function` in the definition.

Comment: @Cleb ok now it works, but i added to print the `x[0], x[1]` and `x[2]` and i see that the constraint that the sum of those 3 should be equal to 100 is not satisfied

Comment: @Cleb please see update 2

Comment: @Cleb No the `fun` is the same. Please keep in mind that the function that i posted is much simpler one than the one that i want to optimize over. I thought that the form of the function wouldn't matter with respect to the `scipy.optimize.minimize`

Comment: the `fun` takes many arguments, one of them is `GP`. I want to optimally allocate 100 `GP` to `x[0], x[1]. x[2]` in order to maximize the `objective_function` which is nothing more than the sum of 3 times `fun` with different input arguments

Comment: See my answer below. This works extremly fast and `x` sums up to `100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general issue regarding your objective function that explains why the values you obtain are very close to each other; it is discussed below.

If we first look at the technical aspect, the following works fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def func(Gp, Ra, Mr, Pot, Sp, Mc, Keep):
    if Keep:
        return Pot * np.tanh((Gp + Ra + Mr + Mc) * Sp)


def objective_function(x, y):

    temp = -(func(x[0], Ra=y['A']['RA'], Mr=y['A']['MR'], Pot=y['A']['POT'], Sp=y['A']['SP'], Mc=y['A']['MC'], Keep=y['A']['keep']) +
             func(x[1], Ra=y['B']['RA'], Mr=y['B']['MR'], Pot=y['B']['POT'], Sp=y['B']['SP'], Mc=y['B']['MC'], Keep=y['B']['keep']) +
             func(x[2], Ra=y['C']['RA'], Mr=y['C']['MR'], Pot=y['C']['POT'], Sp=y['C']['SP'], Mc=y['C']['MC'], Keep=y['C']['keep']))

    return temp


y = {'A': {'RA': 0.5, 'MR': 0.97, 'POT': 0.25, 'SP': 0.25, 'MC': 50., 'keep': True},
     'B': {'RA': 0.8, 'MR': 0.95, 'POT': 0.12, 'SP': 0.12, 'MC': 75., 'keep': True},
     'C': {'RA': 0.9, 'MR': 0.99, 'POT': 0.05, 'SP': 0.15, 'MC': 100., 'keep': True}}

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 100.})

bnds = ((0., None), (0., None), (0., None))

print(minimize(objective_function, x0=np.array([1., 1., 1.]), args=y, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons))
```

This will print

```
    fun: -0.4199999999991943
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 33.33333333,  33.33333333,  33.33333333])
```

As you can see, `x` nicely sums up to `100`.

If you now change `bnds` to e.g.

```
bnds = ((40., 50), (0., None), (0., None))
```

then the result will be

```
     fun: -0.419999999998207
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 40.,  30.,  30.])
```

Again, the constraint is met.

One can also see that the objective value is the same.  That seems to be due to the fact that `Mc` and `Gp` are very large, therefore, `np.tanh` will always just return `1.0`. That implies that you always return just the value `Pot` from `func` for all your three dictionaries in `y`. If you sum up the three corresponding values

```
0.25 + 0.12 + 0.05
```

you indeed get the value `0.42`which is determined by the optimization.

Comment: For these inputs: `y = {'A': {'RA': 0.5, 'MR': 0.97, 'POT': 0.99, 'SP': 0.5, 'MC': 50., 'keep': True},
     'B': {'RA': 0.8, 'MR': 0.95, 'POT': 0, 'SP': 0.0000001, 'MC': 7., 'keep': True},
     'C': {'RA': 0.9, 'MR': 0.99, 'POT': 0.05, 'SP': 0.0000001, 'MC': 1., 'keep': True}}

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 100.})

bnds = ((0., None), (0., None), (0., None))` i get ` x: array([ 33.33333333,  33.33333333,  33.33333333])` which cannot be correct because `y['B']['POT']` is 0, so it should get 0 `GP`, right ?

Comment: @quant: This result is totally fine: With `Pot=0`, `func` returns `0`; so only the other two entries in `y` contribute to your objective. Apparently, the constraint you apply is not limiting so it does not matter whether you set them to `33` or `5` i.e. you don't "waste" resources by allocating `Gp` to a component that contributes `0`. You can easily test this by setting your constraint to `10` instead of `100`; then your objective value does not change as your constraint is not limiting. If you decrease it further, change your initial conditions in such a way that they meet your constraint!

Comment: But i want to maximize the sum of these 3 quantities. So allocating `GP` do a quantity that will give `0` in any case, is a waste of the resources, since it will not add anything to the sum, right ? Which means the `objective_function` would have a larger (in absolute) value if it allocated the 100 `GP` to the other two quantities instead of all 3, no ?

Comment: @quant: No, as explained above. Your constraint is not limiting. When you set `Gp` to `100` you receive the same objective value as for `Gp=10`, so you don't lose anything if you distribute your resource to a component that does not contribute to your objective. The `tanh` saturates quite quickly, so `func` will often just return the same value independent of your input.

Comment: @quant: To give a practical example: You have 100 Dollar and you want to go to three different shops to buy as many bottles of water as possible. In the first shop you spend 10 Dollar and then it runs out of water, in the second shop the same, the third shop does not have any water at all. So you spend in total 20 Dollar, you have 80 Dollar left but you cannot use them to buy more water! So you could also just give them as a gift to the third shop owner and the amount of water bottles does not change for you. That's what is happening here...

Comment: @quant You would have to find a shop that can sell you water for more than 100 Dollar so that your money becomes limiting. Now it is not. It does not matter whether you have 100 dollar or 20 or 2 billion, you always get the same amount of water bottles.

Comment: I saw what my misunderstanding was. The maximum of the `tanh` function is reached at around 2 and i gave big values to the `y`. Now i get it. Thanks !