# Curve fitting with nonlinear constraints with scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: curve-fitting, loss-function, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, scipy-optimize-minimize

Let's say that we want to fit a nonlinear model to our data (that include measurement errors) with certain constraints on the fit parameters among themselves. Without these constraints, `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` does the job as it supports by default the optimization of the

```
chisq = sum((r / sigma) ** 2)
```

where r is the difference between the true and predicted value. Long story short, the user defines a function and pass it to the solver which minimizes the chisq loss. The situation gets a bit more complex when there are other restrictions imposed on the function parameters, e.g. for a linear model y=ax+b, we can demand a fixed nonlinear condition such as a^2+b=1. A function `scipy.optimization.minimize` is just what the doctor ordered, provided that we pass the `chisq` as argument. Below is the code for using `minimize` found [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) [scipy.optimize with non linear constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309877/scipy-optimize-with-non-linear-constraints). I'm struggling very hard in building the `chisq` properly to make the code work. The most general question would how does one defines in the most pythonic way a custom loss that would be minimized?
Help please.

```
from math import cos, atan
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(x):
    return 0.1 * x[0] * x[1]

def ineq_constraint(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 - (5. + 2.2 * cos(10 * atan(x[0] / x[1])))**2


con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': ineq_constraint}
x0 = [1, 1]
res = minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=con)
```

Since we minimize the `chisq` function that is found by optimizing our targeted function, I guess the `chisq` will be defined in a very elegant way in a form of a wrapper since for arguments it takes the targeted function, a column of true values and a column of uncertanties e.g.
`chisq(target_function, (y, y_err))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show a specific example of a function that you'd like to fit subject to some constraints? Your code snippet doesn't correspond to your mentioned example y=a*x+b s.t. a^2 + b = 1.

Comment: I solved it, it required a bit of work but scipy did the job combined with JAX for computing the uncertainties.